# What typeface does Pentagram use for the Sundance Institute brand?

Tags: font-identification

Total beginner here. What typeface does Pentagram use for the Sundance Institute? Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

[image: Sundance Institute brand identity]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trade Gothic with a modified "d". It's stated in the linked article about the new logo.

http://www.creativebloq.com/logo-design/sundance-festival-8134113
https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/trade-gothic/

[image]